# How to open or use .all files

Tags: qgis, file-formats

I have downloaded what multibeam sonar datasets from the marine geoscience data system website http://www.marine-geo.org/index.php

The files have arrived in a .tar folder which contains multiple files with the name `SOME_UNIQUE_ID_raw.all.gz`. If I use gunzip to unzip a file I get a `.all` file which i've never encountered before.

Some googling says it contains multiple files but I've no idea how to open it.

Any ideas how to use it? I'm on the latest version of qGIS

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question and post a link to a specific file or search terms which would enable us to find the actual files you are talking about...

Comment: According to this [sourceforge forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/354013/thread/f639a837/), the extensions `.all` = "all laser last"; `.alf` = "all laser first". Quoting the forum: _"You can import such files to SAGA with the Import/Export - Shapes / Import Point Cloud from Text File module."_

Comment: Or Kongsberg echosounder data files ([.all](http://support.echoview.com/WebHelp/Reference/File_formats/Kongsberg_data_files.htm))